# How to generate list of Java EE web services?

Tags: java, maven, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-7

## Problem

I need to document all of our Java EE application's web services.

Our application is a Maven project. I need to include information such as:

- Service Name
- Module
- Package
- Class
- Method
- Code Usages [if possible]

Currently I am trying to do it the manually way of scouring the code for occurrences of *@WebService* & *@WebServiceClient* and writing it into a spreadsheet. But this process is excruciating.

## Efforts

I have tried looking at the *Java Enterprise* tab in IntelliJ, I got my hopes up for a second but then I noticed that it repeats many web services throughout the various Maven modules. Also, I haven't found a way to export the list of web services so I'd have to write them each manually anyway.

I briefly looked at the ASM project (as suggested by @JF_Meier), but that seems like too steep of a learning curve to be feasible right now. I get frowned upon when I go off on a tangent and spent more time on an "efficient" process rather than just getting on with it.

I looked at Maven, hoping there would be something like a *mvn dependency:tree*, but for web services. I have yet to find something of the sorts.

## Question

**Is there more efficient way to generate a list of web service in a Maven / Java EE applcation?**

Comment: Certainly, I believe it can be achieved in a more efficient way, kind of write a method executed on start up and scan all classes looking for those annotation which indicate what you need. On the other hand the question is way to broad to be answered here (my opinion)

Comment: @lealceldeiro, you are quite right in it being a broad question - do you have suggestions and how I could narrow it?

Comment: Post what you have tried(code), explain what it does (if needed) and where it is failing. If you have not implemented anything yet, well I already gave you a clue about how to do it (a general idea of how to approach the problem). But most importantly tried to research in the web how to do this, I mean, no code, but the idea about how to approach this kind of problem, when you get the idea, well, let's get our hands (yours :) ) on the code. After that then you will have specific problems such as "how to executed a method on start up?", "how to scan all java classes in a project", and so on.

Comment: Remember, some users here get annoyed by the fact that they think your are trying to get them doing you (home|project)work.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I thought I had described my process, being one of manually searching through the code. but I'll try to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like asm to scan the byte code for annotations.

It allows you to walk through the code with a visitor. Then you can look for annotations like `@WebService`.